# make sounds (beep) with c++

Tags: c++

How to make the hardware beep sound with c++?

Comment: toot is a cross-platform C file that try to call several sound generators to produce the beep. http://github.com/vareille/toot

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Print the **special character** `ASCII BEL` (code 7)

```
cout << '\a';
```

[Source](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/127539-making-computer-speaker-beep#post443147)

Comment: This comes out of speakers. How can I make the internal motherboard make a beep instead of speaker?

Comment: That depends on the operating system. Old MS-DOS triggered a motherboard sound with that. If you are running a very recent OS I expect the kernel to trigger an audio signal from speaker rather than using hardware

Comment: this is not working I tried full volume, my g++ version is `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0`

Answer (score 70):

If you're using Windows OS then there is a function called `Beep()`

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> // WinApi header 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    Beep(523,500); // 523 hertz (C5) for 500 milliseconds     
    cin.get(); // wait 
    return 0; 
}
```

Source: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread15252.html

For Linux based OS there is:

```
echo -e "\007" >/dev/tty10
```

And if you do not wish to use `Beep()` in windows you can do:

```
echo "^G"
```

Source: http://www.frank-buss.de/beep/index.html

Comment: For the last one, this does NOT work when I enter `^` and `G`. It only works when pressing `Ctrl+G`. Even though the strings look the same when entered, they are different and are also printed differently.

Comment: `Beep()` function plays sound via speakers, not through motherboard's physical buzzer. According to microsoft website : "because of the lack of hardware to communicate with, support for Beep was dropped in Windows Vista and Windows XP 64-Bit Edition.

In Windows 7, Beep was rewritten to pass the beep to the default sound device for the session"

Comment: that's a beautiful beep

Answer (score 8):

There are a few OS-specific routines for beeping.

- On a Unix-like OS, try [the (n)curses beep() function](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_beep.3x.html).  This is likely to be more portable than writing `'\a'` as others have suggested, although for most terminal emulators that will probably work.
- In some *BSDs there is a [PC speaker device](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=speaker&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html).  Reading the driver source, the `SPKRTONE` ioctl seems to correspond to the raw hardware interface, but there also seems to be a high-level language built around `write()`-ing strings to the driver, described in the manpage.
- It looks like Linux has a similar driver (see [this article](http://www.webcitation.org/query?url=http://www.geocities.com/stssppnn/pcsp.html&date=2009-10-25+22:26:34) for example; there is also some example code on [this page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/kernel-beep-manipulation-605355/) if you scroll down a bit.).
- In Windows there is a function called [Beep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: '\a' is defined by the C++ standard, and is extremely portable.  Of course if you're using broken terminal software all bets are off, but the Win32 console subsystem and most xterm clones all process '\a' properly.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the C++ standard only specify that '\a' will represent an ASCII BEL character; but it never specifies what the programs' behavior should be when sending such character to stdout. The part that ASCII BEL == '\a' is extremely portable, as you said, but the beeping part is a totally undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ben: as far as I'm concerned, terminal software is broken if it *doesn't* have a way of switching off the bell.

Comment: @Steve: I agree, but I don't read this question is "How do you make a beep when the users has explicitly turned sounds off?"

Answer (score 5):

alternatively in c or c++ after including stdio.h

```
char d=(char)(7);
printf("%c\n",d);
```

(char)7 is called the bell character.

Answer (score 5):

You could use conditional compilation:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <Windows.h>
void beep() {
  Beep(440, 1000);
}
#elif LINUX
#include <stdio.h>
void beep() {
  system("echo -e "\007" >/dev/tty10");
}
#else
#include <stdio.h>
void beep() {
  cout << "\a" << flush;
}
#endif
```

Comment: It is better to let LINUX part to be flexible with frequency and time too, using 'system("beep -f 5000 -l 50 -r 2") ' ( see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker )

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
cout << '\a';
```

From [C++ Character Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> Alert: \a

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << '\7';
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried most things here, none worked on my Ubuntu VM.

Here is a quick hack (credits goes [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163716)):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  system("(speaker-test -t sine -f 1000)& pid=$!; sleep 1.0s; kill -9 $pid");
}
```

It will basically use system's `speaker-test` to produce the sound. This will not terminate quickly though, so the command runs it in background (the `&` part), then captures its process id (the `pid=$1` part), sleeps for a certain amount that you can change (the `sleep 1.0s` part) and then it kills that process (the `kill -9 $pid` part).

`sine` is the sound produced. You can change it to `pink` or to a `wav` file.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probbaly just to print a ^G ascii bell

Comment: `stdout`, perhaps?  There's no object named `out` in `namespace std`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Beep(1568, 200);
    Beep(1568, 200);
    Beep(1568, 200);
    Beep(1245, 1000);
    Beep(1397, 200);
    Beep(1397, 200);
    Beep(1397, 200);
    Beep(1175, 1000);

cout<<endl;
_getch()

return 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The ASCII bell character might be what you are looking for.  Number 7 in [this](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html) table.

Answer (score -1):

```
cout << "\a";
```

In Xcode, After compiling, you have to run the executable by hand to hear the beep.