# How to make Motherboard Beep through C++ Code?

Tags: c++, hardware, motherboard

How can I make the motherboard internal speaker produce sounds, for example using the Beep command but directed towards the **motherboards speakers**.

> OS = Windows 7 x64

I currently know how to provide beeps to the default sound device, including tone and millisecond's but this does not answer my question since I cant force any of these sounds towards the motherboard internal speakers.

```
Beep(523, 500);
```

My question is mainly based around an alternative to Beep which would play through the motherboards speakers rather than the computer audio card. Or a way to direct the Beep command or incoming audio frequencies towards the motherboards speakers.

Comment: You can't expect us to give you code?

Comment: Did you google that? It is unclear what you are asking here or/and too broad

Comment: FirstStep, I googled this, but received no real answer for Windows 7.

Comment: Define "_real answer_"? And did you start with any base code?

Comment: Using the Beep(hertz, milli) and trying /a in the console. Although that only directed it to my default sound device as I expected.

Comment: @FirstStep dude, what? How would it be possible to start with base code for something that is not known how to do?

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin wow calm down. OP could have improved the Q if wanted to get better responses. Why did not he provide that small code in the OP instead of the comment then?

Comment: @FirstStep could you inform me how to better improve the question in order for the community to provide better answers? I am quite new as you might be able to tell and would appreciate any feedback I can get.

Comment: This question seems reasonable scoped, hence I can't see why it needs a code attempt. However the community is full of homework question so they all expect some code, for example you could add that Beep... only send to default sound device (to make them less skeptic and show that you understand some of the issues.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I think I edited the question to be more descriptive.

Comment: Err...this may not be what your looking for, but like this?  std::cout<<"\a"; EDIT: nevermind see you already tried that.

Comment: @DarthFutuza no sorry, I just tested it and it only provides you with the Windows error / notification beep, not a motherboard beep or even a specified frequency, but thank you.

Comment: I have edited your post to send it in to re-open que, if you have more details consider to future improve your question.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I edited it a bit more but I couldn't find that much more to add, thanks for editing it yourself as well.

Comment: this question seems similar, maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060601/make-sounds-beep-with-c

Comment: @PetterFriberg I saw that one before making this question and it did not answer the question I had for Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Consider editing into the question, to avoid duplicate, explaining why it does not work

Comment: This may also be of interest http://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt, moving on I hope it gets re-opened

Comment: @PetterFriberg the reasons why these don't help is because they mainly pertain to making a real Beep through the sound card, and when they are specifically talking about the motherboard internal speakers, it requires you to replace windows operating system files, which I cannot do in this particular instance.

Comment: Lots of good stuff to explain in question : ), show research effort, explain all requirements etc.

Answer (score 3):

#### The question was later specified to refer to Win32 programming environment, this question describes a Linux solution.

You can use the `KIOCSOUND` ioctl to generate a tone, as such

```
ioctl(fd,KIOCSOUND,(int) tone)
```

[The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/) is a fabulous book that describes using IOCTLs in detail, but there are public resources that describe the IOCTL such as the perennially [classic TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node83.html).

Comment: I appreciate the response and it would be perfect although I am not running linux for my operating system, although ill keep that line of code in case I need it at a later time!

Comment: @ITCSB Next time consider tagging platform-sensitive questions with `[linux]` or `[windows]` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7, Beep was rewritten to pass the beep to the default sound device for the session. This is normally the sound card, except when run under Terminal Services, in which case the beep is rendered on the client. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx)

There is apparently one possible modification of system descibed [here](https://superuser.com/a/230167/506548).

Comment: This seems great, but it wouldn't work for my needs, I am trying to create a song with beep commands and then give it to my friend who wouldn't want his computer system files being changed in any shape or form.