# System beep NodeJS custom frequency and duration

Tags: javascript, node.js, beep

I'm trying to make a custom motherboard beep with NodeJS.
Right now I'm using `process.stderr.write("\007");`, which makes a default system beep on my motherboard (Windows 7 64).

But some programming languages have something like:
`SoundBeep, Frequency, Duration` (AutoHotKey: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundBeep.htm)

And apparently it's also possible in C++:
`Beep(hertz, milli)` ([How to make Motherboard Beep through C++ Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883092/how-to-make-motherboard-beep-through-c-code))

Is setting custom system beep frequency and duration possible in NodeJS?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/a1-beep library that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a C++ addon for this and C++ `Beep(frequency, duration)` function.
I took examples from this repository: https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples (the second example, nan),
modified it to pass my arguments (frequency and duration), then compiled the `addon.cc` file using the instructions in that repository.

So in nodeJS I can pass this to the addon:

```
addon.add(frequency,duration);
```

And in C++

```
double arg0 = info[0]->NumberValue(context).FromJust();
double arg1 = info[1]->NumberValue(context).FromJust();
Beep(arg0,arg1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do

```
powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,600)
```

So in node.js it would look like this

```
require("child_process").exec("powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,600)");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think for `windows` more easy to do via rundll32 tool and [beep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/utilapiset/nf-utilapiset-beep)

```
const cp = require('child_process');

function beep(frequency, duration) {
  cp.execSync(`rundll32.exe Kernel32.dll,Beep ${frequency},${duration}`);
}

beep(750,300);
```

Comment: Not beeping currently. Do I need any additional files? I just put everything above in a js file and run it with node? Also it's Win7 64

Comment: On my box it works without any problems. Just run in console `rundll32.exe Kernel32.dll,Beep 750,300`

Comment: Couldn't make it work after experimenting, just returns a new line. Something like this `rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep` works, but doesn't produce the sound I need

Comment: Here it's said Beep isn't supported on 64 Vista and 64 XP: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=netframework-4.8`. Also maybe it has to do with the fact that I replaced `Beep.sys` with the one from XP 64 to use motherboard for beeps instead of the speakers. It works fine in AutoHotKey though

Comment: Also it worked in c++ for me: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060601/make-sounds-beep-with-c` with the second answer