# C++ Not Beeping

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I am writing this program that should beep when I run it. I searched everywhere and I really feel like my code is correct, but I just don't hear the beep. (My speakers are on too) Please help!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //please beep
    cout << "\a";
    cout << "other text" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the actual terminal you're using.

Comment: @JAB No they expect to `'\a'` is ringing the bell.

Comment: @JAB '\a' is the bell char: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Comment: like @πάνταῥεῖ said, depends on the terminal. The terminal decides to beep or to send a notification to your window manager, or flash, or anything.

Comment: what platform you are using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 5):

If writing a `'\a'` (aka the `BEL` character according the [ASCII table](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.asciitable.com/&h=488&w=715&tbnid=2U31hF4tTw886M:&tbnh=90&tbnw=132&docid=JMtOixefP_tDJM&usg=__ybvv7Ki0b-gOh-P1dJXP4Ou_jsU=&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjC0brntPHOAhWCWywKHcvYBO4Q9QEIHjAA)) produces a sound or not,  depends on the particular terminal implementation.

Writing that character to the console doesn't guarantee to produce an audible signal. Some terminals might ring a bell, others may flash for a second, else ones may completely ignore it.

---

Well, from other answers there seem to be situations, where the terminal is closed prior the audible signal is applied.

Using some mechanism, to keep your application/terminal left open long enough by using some blocking operation like `cin.get()` before your application exits might help.

Answer (score 4):

This is dependent on the terminal.

Similar questions:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162632/terminal-not-beeping-on-bell-character

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep

[make sounds (beep) with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060601/make-sounds-beep-with-c)

Ultimately, it is up to your terminal to produce the beep sound. The same code run in different environments may behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the Standard C++ `cout << '\a'` , On Windows, there is also a function called `Beep()`.

`Beep()` is written to pass the beep to the default sound device for the session. This is normally the sound card, except when run under Terminal Services, in which case the beep is rendered on the client.

Usage: `Beep( Frequency_Herz , Duration_Milliseconds );`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

C++ Code For the Super Mario Bros Theme and Intro Song

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


int main(){

        Beep (330,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(700);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
        Beep (262,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (196,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (164,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (220,300);Sleep(100);
        Beep (246,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (233,200);
        Beep (220,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(150);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(150);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(150);
        Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (247,100);Sleep(500);
        Beep (262,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (196,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (164,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (220,300);Sleep(100);
        Beep (246,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (233,200);
        Beep (220,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(150);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(150);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(150);
        Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (247,100);Sleep(900);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (207,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(500);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (523,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (523,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (523,100);Sleep(1100);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (207,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(500);
        Beep (311,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (296,300);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,300);Sleep(1300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,200);Sleep(50);
        Beep (262,200);Sleep(50);
        Beep (220,200);Sleep(50);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(700);
        Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(500);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,200);Sleep(50);
        Beep (262,200);Sleep(50);
        Beep (220,200);Sleep(50);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
        /*Intro*/
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(700);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
        Beep (196,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (330,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (392,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (523,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (660,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (784,100);Sleep(575);
        Beep (660,100);Sleep(575);
        Beep (207,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (262,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (311,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (415,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (523,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (622,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (830,100);Sleep(575);
        Beep (622,100);Sleep(575);
        Beep (233,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (294,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (349,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (466,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (587,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (698,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (932,100);Sleep(575);
        Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
        Beep (1046,675);    


    return 0;
}
```