# Remove "\" from CString in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How can I remove this character `\` from CString?

For Example: I have string with this content "this is\a string"

How can I remove `\` from my string?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: Does it make [\a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060601/make-sounds-beep-with-c) sound?

Comment: Your question is unclear.    Does the string print to `std::cout` as `this is \a string` (i.e. the backslash and the 'a' are visible on screen) or as `this is  string` (with the backslash and and the 'a' not visible?     There are different solutions for each case.

Comment: You remove the `\\` character from a string like you would remove any other character from a string. This is a trivial operation, exposed through the [CSting::Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#remove) class member.

Comment: @IInspectable He may not realise that `\` is a prefix for formatting codes like `\t`. So iif he wants to delete a `\` he probably has to use `\\`. But I know you know that! :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thank you all for your support. Sorry for my question is not clear. Actually, I have 2 problem here. The 1st is: Trying to remove this '\' from a string  "\" ", I had try many ways like remove(), delete() but it does not work. The 2nd is: How can I declare CString like this: CString = _T(" include "abc.h"  "); It always built false with not correct form. But I dont know how to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I found my problem. The string ' \" ' when print to window  only ' " ' will be printed. So I do not need to remove '\' any more. My problem is solved. Thank you so much, I understood this issue.

Answer (score 5):

It's simple for a `CString`:

```
cstr.Remove('\\');
```

Comment: Not sure if the OP _actually_ wants just to remove the `\`. Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: It does not work with this CString = "\""

Comment: @HieuLe `.Remove('\"')` in this case, where is the problem ?

Comment: @Blacktempel: Yah, I only want to remove '\' only.

Comment: @Blacktempel: I found my problem. The string ' \" ' when print to window only ' " ' will be printed. So I do not need to remove '\' any more. My problem is solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: @HieuLe Of course not, it is just an [escape sequence.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Answer (score -4):

```
  #include <algorithm>
  ...
  // Use replace with substitute a space in place of the \ char.
  std::replace(my_string.begin(), my_string.end(), '\\', ' ');
  // or remove it all together.
  std::remove(my_string.begin(), my_string.end(), '\\')
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a `CString`.